# Logarithm function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ a region $\mathcal{L}:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ a logarithm function and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ a continuous function such that $(f(z))^n = z$ for all $z\in\Omega$. Prove that there is $0\leq k\leq n-1$ such that $f(z)=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}e^{\frac{1}{n}\mathcal{L}(z)}$ for all $z\in\Omega$

Idea: if $\mathcal{L}:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is a logarithm function then $e^{\mathcal{L}(z)}=z$ for all $z\in\Omega$. Note that:  $(f(z))^n=z=(e^{{2\pi i}}e^{\frac{1}{n}\mathcal{L}(z)})^n=e^{{2\pi in}}e^{\mathcal{L}(z)}$ But I don't know how to continue, can anyone help me? Please

Thanks

Comment: In the last equation, it should read $e^{2\pi i n}$ rather than $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$. What can you say about the function $z \mapsto f(z)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{n}\mathcal{L}(z)}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks you, $(f(z)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{n}\mathcal{L}(z)})^n=1$. What do you mean?

Comment: That's one important thing about it. What does that tell you about the values this function may attain? And then, what can you say about regularity properties (analyticity, smoothness, continuity, …) of that function?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is clearly continuous since $f$ and $\mathcal{L}$ are. But I still don't understand the idea of ​​the test. Could you explain a little more please? thank you..

Comment: Good. So we have a continuous function $g$ that satisfies $g(z)^n = 1$ for all $z \in \Omega$. Look at how $g$ is defined, and what you want to show, and then think about how you can obtain that from the properties of $g$ stated at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Define $g(z)=f(z)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{n}\mathcal{L}(z)}$, $(g(z))^n=1$ for all $z\in\Omega$.

Then $g(z)$ it is a root of unity, therefore it exists $k\in{\{0,1,2,...,n-1}\}$ such that $g(z)=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$ for all $z\in\Omega$.

Then $g(z)=f(z)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{n}\mathcal{L}(z)}=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$. Hence $f(z)= e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}e^{\frac{1}{n}\mathcal{L}(z)}$ for all $z\in\Omega$.

Comment: Yes, but you should also mention why the $k$ is the same for all $z \in \Omega$. From $\bigl(g(z)\bigr)^n \equiv 1$ it only follows that for each $z$ there is a $k(z)$ such that $g(z) = e^{2\pi i k(z)/n}$. What guarantees that the same $k$ works for all $z$?